# Add namespace in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

I have VS2012, by using C# i created two WPF, and I added a button to first WPF to open the second WPF. But VS couldnt found the Window ( I wrote this:

```
 MainWindow_2 win2 = new MainWindow_2().Show();
 win2.Show();
```

and it couldnt find MainWindow_2)

I tried to add a namespace "DXWPFApplication3" to another Window. I tried:

```
using DXWPFApplication3;
```

and it gives error "type or namespace name could not be found"

How can i add a namespace?

(In Project folder those two WPFs in different folders)

Comment: holy terrible formatting, batman!

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, feel free to improve the formatting, by pressing the "edit" link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Just like zespri said... Say its wrong without telling how to fix it or fixing it yourself is nothing constructive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a reference to the first project.
Open the project up in Solution Explorer, right click on the References and click "Add Reference". In that dialog, pick projects and add the project that has the `DXWPFApplication3` namespace. That should fix the problem.